# How to create a Default Argument based on Tags

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I need to create a view block where users who have entered a specific tag on their personal profile page are displayed. I have the page set and it works properly. I just need to know how to set up the default argument based on context when associating that specific tag.

There are 2 types of profiles:

- business (has a tag field X)
- employee (has same tag field X)

Business owners have personal and a business profile access. Employees just have access to the personal profile.

For those employees that have a matching tag with the business profile I need them listed in a block as employees on that company/business profile page.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance I think you should create a taxonomy view with relationship to the content type where it was use by the user, then create a contextual filter to filter the nodes where the user is the author.

I am not sure if the tags created by the user will get the uid of the user that created out of the box, but if you can control that then the view will be even simpler just a taxonomy view with a contextual filter to the field holding the uid by the login user.

Comment: that's not the case... the tags only show up in profile2 fields... Here is the scenario -- There are 2 types of profiles one for business owners the other for employees. The business owners have personal and a business profile access. The employees just have a personal. For those employees that have a matching tag with the business profile I need them listed in a block as employees on that company/business profile page.

Comment: The other tough concern is that new users will create new tags so I have a difficult time managing all of the profile patterns in the future. I can't let it be set on anything static. I have the relationship set to user:profile. I then have a contextual filter on the vocabulary. The next problem is that I need this view to show up anywhere. The only way that I can think of is through default argument from context. I don't know how to set the namespace and attributes for a vocabulary term.

Comment: For your second comment this module might help: http://drupal.org/project/private_taxonomy

Comment: Are the tags on the profile a taxonomy reference field?

Comment: Yes the field is a taxonomy reference with tag feature. --- I don't know if I am in need of private taxonomy since the taxonomy isn't on a show/hide basis... It's just to organize the content to be shown in an appropriate delimitation. Everybody should be able to see this block.